How to Convert Forms Authentication Cookie from .NET Framework 4.8 to AuthenticationTicket in .NET 8?
I am working on integrating two systems. System A is built with .NET 8, and System B is using .NET Framework 4.8 with Forms Authentication. I need to retrieve the Forms Authentication cookie from System B and convert it into an AuthenticationTicket in System A for user authentication.
Can someone provide guidance on how to:

Decrypt the Forms Authentication cookie from System B in .NET 8.
Convert the decrypted cookie into an AuthenticationTicket in .NET 8.

I tried using AspNetTicketBridge, but this package only converts OWIN cookies into AuthenticationTicket and cannot convert Forms Authentication cookies.

You have to choose an option that supports by both sides, and forms authentication isn't such.
